# Watson Assistant creating a go back option for all nodes

Tags: json, python-3.x, watson-assistant

I would like to create a "back to previous" button after each response for users who realize that they inputted the wrong answer and would like to start over

Comment: Hi, Mmihi. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please provide some more detail. For example, any code you have written. Providing more detail will increase the likelihood of you getting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in the last version of Watson Assistant you need to create an **Intent** ("go_back" for example) and then use the **Jump** functionality to go back to the previous node if the go_back intent is recognized -- a **Jump** must be manually configured in all nodes where you want "go_back" to be possible in your Dialog.

I hope this answer helps you.

Comment: How can a go back intent be recognized after a response without the intent?

Comment: What i mean is I would like there to be an "option" to go back to previous regardless of whether someone asks for it

Comment: If nobody asks for it (through text input or option button click) there is no way your Assistant will "know" it has to "go back". Can you provide a detailed dialog example of user inputs and what response you expect from the Assistant?

Comment: On the welcome node, I have 4 options that the user responds to by selecting one. What if he realized that he didn't want to pick that option. He cannot go back to the welcome to restart. Can I share a screenshot here?

Comment: You can update your question with the screenshot.